# Is there a way to Override the same javascript for different inputs locally?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

So, suppose there is a html code that has two buttons, A and B. Both buttons call the same javascript, say Callscript(), but with different inputs, that is A calls with Callscript(A) and B calls with Callscript(B). I have overridden the response of Button A to a local file, and I want B to get the usual response, but the response of button B is also being Overridden.

I want to override only the response of button A, but not of B. Is this possible in Chrome's Overrides option?

Comment: You should probably add a snippet of your Callscript() function

Comment: What does "I have overridden the response of Button A to a local file" mean exactly?

Comment: @Jamiec there is a feature in Devtools called Overrides, that is what I have used.

Comment: @jna this is not my website, I have just used the Override feature from Devtools to change some small things in it, so I do not have access to all the scripts.

Comment: You should add the code snippet, and if possible, please include jsfiddle.